# Exporting To ONNX From R

Tags: r, onnx

How to export a machine learning model to ONNX format in R?

I have this R package for ONNX, it's ONNX v 0.0.3, but it doesn't have documentation and the documentation that is available on the official website isn't really beginner friendly. I read it from start to finish but I didn't understand much of it if I'm being honest.

I've exported to ONNX before in Python, it's really straightforward and easy to follow along, however there's almost nothing available on how to export from R, from what I've read so far R doesn't have native support for this utility, is that still the case or have we moved forward?

onnx package in R

[image]